# How do I tidy lyrics data?

Tags: r

I imported a txt file into R, but part of the data shows up as a blank white square in one row. When I hover over the square, I can see the lyrics data separated by commas, but I'm not sure how to tidy the data for analysis.

I used the following code to import the data:

```r
mxm <- read.delim("mxm_dataset_train.txt") 
colnames(mxm) <-c("Description") 
mxm <- mxm[-c(1:16), ]
```

I removed the first 16 rows because they were comments.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Comment: Try `read.csv` or `read.csv2`